# Do not show numberpicker divider

Tags: android, divider, numberpicker

I use the following attribute to don't show numberpicker dividers, but it does not have any effects

```
<NumberPicker
android:id="@+id/TNP_M"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:showDividers="none"/>
```

What's the problem, should I use another attribute to do this?

**UPDATE-1**

[image]

I changed height and width, and now as you can see the dividers' position is not correct, so I decided not to show them, I set the "showDivders" attribute to "none" but it does not affect the numbetpicker.

Comment: can you show a screenshot?

Comment: you can use `numberpickerobject.setShowDividers(0);`

Comment: @Prag'sシ Does not work ! :(

Comment: define transperent color to color.xml and try to set "android:divider=@color/transperent".. its tricky but may work for you..

Answer (score 1):

Using this codes

```
 Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field pf : pickerFields) {
            if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
                pf.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    pf.set(daypicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
                    pf.set(mounthpicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
                    pf.set(yearpicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setShowDividers(int)

Comment: and SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE opt.